# Converting xml beans to java config issue

Tags: java, spring, java-8, javabeans, xmlbeans

I have a bean in xml:

```
<bean id="fooBean" class="org.model.Foo" scope="prototype">
    <property name="propOne" ref="fooBarOne"/>
    <property name="propTwo" ref="fooBarTwo"/>
    <property name="propThree" ref="fooBarThree"/>
</bean>
```

I converted it in java like this:

```
@Bean
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public Foo fooBean(
    FooBarOneImpl fooBarOne,
    FooBarTwoImpl fooBarTwo,
    FooBarThreeImpl fooBarThree
) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setPropOne(fooBarOne);
    foo.setPropTwo(fooBarTwo);
    foo.setPropThree(fooBarThree);
    return foo;
}
```

When I execute:

```
(IFoo) applicationContext.getBean("fooBean", pizza, patatine, cocaCola);
```

with the xml config it works correctly, with Java config it gives I get an Exception.
The exception is the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.model.Foo]: Illegal arguments to factory method 'fooBean'; args: "ciao","11","abc"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

The class Foo has the constructor defined Foo(String pizza, String patatine, String cocaCola){...}.

Why when the bean is defined in the xml it finds the right constructor?

I tried to change the java conversion

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Bean
public FooBarOne propOne() { // Bean name will be set by method name
    return new FooBarOne(); // if FooBarOne is an interface, use here any implementation
}

@Bean
public FooBarTwo propTwo() { // Bean name will be set by method name
    return new FooBarTwo(); // if FooBarTwo is an interface, use here any implementation
}

@Bean 
public FooBarThree propThree() { // Bean name will be set by method name
    return new FooBarThree(); // if FooBarThree is an interface, use here any implementation
}

@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public Foo fooBean(FooBarOne a, FooBarTwo b, FooBarThree c) {
    // Here, I linked by type name and not bean name. The name of the parameter is optional, it can be anything you like.
    // If you want to link by bean name, use @Qualified annotation.
    // This annotation is needed if the bean injection is not trivial.
    return new Foo(a, b, c)
}
```

Another critical topic: If you defined a CLASS return type, we can't be referencing the instance's interface.

```java
interface I {}
class A implemented I {}

// ------------------------------------------------------

@Bean
public A a() { return new A() }

@Bean
public A a(I instance) { ... } // ERROR
@Bean
public A a(A instance) { ... } // OK

// ------------------------------------------------------

@Bean
public I a() { return new A() }

@Bean
public A a(I instance) { ... } // OK
@Bean
public A a(A instance) { ... } // ERROR
```

If you use @Service/@Repository/@Component on your class, you can do ref because Spring will scan your project. Spring won't do it via @Bean because @Bean is the direct definition.

Comment: I alreay defined the three FooBar beans and Foo class don't have the constructor for those 3, Foo has a constuctor with  "pizza, patatine, cocaCola" that are not beans

Comment: Can you rewrite this? `Foo class don't have the constructor` and `Foo has a constuctor with ...` so Foo has or hasn't constructor?

Comment: Foo has two constructors:
    public Foo() {}

    public Foo(String anno, String numero, String gioco) {
        this.anno = anno;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.gioco = gioco;
    }

The FooBar beans you see in the declaration are set using setters.

Comment: Does not matter whether the constructor is exist or not. The point is to return an object that is "ready". How you solve this (setter or via constructor) is your responsibility.

Comment: I know it's my responsability, my question is: why with the bean defined in the xml I can call "(IFoo) applicationContext.getBean("fooBean", pizza, patatine, cocaCola);" but when the bean is defined in java I get the exception?

Comment: OK. These are variable names only. What are they? String? objects? According to error message, these are strings. `Illegal arguments to factory method 'fooBean'; args: "ciao","11","abc"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`

Comment: They variables are of the correct type, the code is the same in both cases.